Fastest key value grouping
Given an array of <key, value> pairs, what is the state-of-the-art approach to group the keys together by values?
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <execution>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/concurrent_unordered_map.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <chrono>


template<typename timetype = std::chrono::microseconds>
struct tiktok
{
  std::vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> > starts;
  void reset() { starts.reserve(50); starts.resize(0); }
  tiktok() { reset(); }
  std::size_t tik() {  
    starts.emplace_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()); 
    return 0; 
  }
  std::size_t tok() { 
    std::size_t rst = std::chrono::duration_cast<timetype> (
      std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - starts.back()).count();
    starts.pop_back();
    return rst;
  }
};


int main()
{
  int NuniqueString = 3e5;
  std::vector<std::string > x(NuniqueString);
  std::mt19937 rng(123);
  for (auto& u: x) { 
    u = std::string(rng() % 1024 + 1, ' ');
    char* c = &u[0];
    for (int i = 0, iend = u.size(); i < iend; ++i)
      c[i] = rng() % 256;
  } 
  
  // The key-value pair definition.
  struct Item { int key; std::string s; };
  std::vector<Item> items(x.size() * 10);
  for (int i = 0, iend = items.size(); i < iend; ++i) { 
    items[i].key = i;
    items[i].s = x[rng() % NuniqueString];
  } 
  auto itemsReserve = items;
  
  // Measure time cost for grouping items' keys, using STL unordered_map
  tiktok timer;
  if constexpr (true) { 
    std::unordered_map<
      std::string, std::vector<int> > H (items.size() * 1.3);
    timer.tik();
    std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), [&](auto& i)->void { 
      H[std::move(i.s)].push_back(i.key);
    }); 
    std::cout << "Sequential, use STL unordered_map time cost (ms) = " << 
      timer.tok() << "\n\n";
  } 
  
  // Measure time cost using tbb concurrent unordered_map and concurrent vector.
  if constexpr (true) { 
    items = itemsReserve;
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<
      std::string, tbb::concurrent_vector<int>, 
      std::hash<std::string> > H(items.size() * 1.3);
    timer.tik();
    std::for_each( std::execution::par_unseq, items.begin(), 
                   items.end(), [&](auto& i)->void { 
        auto it = H.insert(std::pair(
          std::move(i.s),
          tbb::concurrent_vector<int>()));
        it.first->second.push_back(i.key);
      }); 
    std::cout << "Parallel, use tbb concurrent unordered_map and"
    " concurrent vector time cost (ms) = " << timer.tok() << "\n\n";
  }
}

g++ -std=c++20 groupStrings.cpp -Ofast -march=native -o test -ltbb on a 16-core machine produces the following:
Sequential, use STL unordered_map time cost (ms) = 1700035

Parallel, use tbb concurrent unordered_map and concurrent vector time cost (ms) = 1575196

I need to frequently perform such groupings for massive arrays of key-value pairs. To start rolling my own treatment, is there any SOTA approach for solving it?

Side note: Be careful with -Ofast unless you are completely aware of (and OK with) the consequences, otherwise just stick to -O2 or -O3.

My colleagues use Parlay.

Have you checket how long reading all the items (key and value) takes (e.g. and adding all hash-values of the values (to ensure that optimization does not remove all the readsing))? This is the absolute minimum time you cannot beat however fast your data-structure is.

The problem is that the strings should not be moved into tbb::concurrent_unordered_map:
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <execution>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/concurrent_unordered_map.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <chrono>


template<typename timetype = std::chrono::microseconds>
struct tiktok
{
  std::vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> > starts;
  void reset() { starts.reserve(50); starts.resize(0); }
  tiktok() { reset(); }
  std::size_t tik() {  
    starts.emplace_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()); 
    return 0; 
  }
  std::size_t tok() { 
    std::size_t rst = std::chrono::duration_cast<timetype> (
      std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - starts.back()).count();
    starts.pop_back();
    return rst;
  }
};


int main()
{
  int NuniqueString = 3e5;
  std::vector<std::string > x(NuniqueString);
  std::mt19937 rng(123);
  for (auto& u: x) { 
    u = std::string(rng() % 1024 + 1, ' ');
    char* c = &u[0];
    for (int i = 0, iend = u.size(); i < iend; ++i)
      c[i] = rng() % 256;
  } 
  
  // The key-value pair definition.
  struct Item { int key; std::string s; };
  std::vector<Item> items(x.size() * 10);
  for (int i = 0, iend = items.size(); i < iend; ++i) { 
    items[i].key = i;
    items[i].s = x[rng() % NuniqueString];
  } 
  auto itemsReserve = items;
  
  // Measure time cost for grouping items' keys, using STL unordered_map
  tiktok timer;
  if constexpr (true) { 
    std::unordered_map<
      std::string, std::vector<int> > H (items.size() * 1.3);
    timer.tik();
    std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), [&](auto& i)->void { 
      H[std::move(i.s)].push_back(i.key);
    }); 
    std::cout << "Sequential, use STL unordered_map time cost (ms) = " << 
      timer.tok() << "\n\n";
  } 
  
  // Measure time cost using tbb concurrent unordered_map and concurrent vector.
  if constexpr (true) { 
    items = itemsReserve;
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<
      std::string, tbb::concurrent_vector<int>, 
      std::hash<std::string> > H(items.size() * 1.3);
    timer.tik();
    std::for_each( std::execution::par_unseq, items.begin(), 
                   items.end(), [&](auto& i)->void { 
        auto it = H.insert(std::pair(
          i.s, // std::move(i.s),
          tbb::concurrent_vector<int>()));
        it.first->second.push_back(i.key);
      }); 
    std::cout << "Parallel, use tbb concurrent unordered_map and"
    " concurrent vector time cost (ms) = " << timer.tok() << "\n\n";
  }
}

This prints:
Sequential, use STL unordered_map time cost (ms) = 1691195

Parallel, use tbb concurrent unordered_map and concurrent vector time cost (ms) = 423323

4x speedup is not bad. But now the question is, why is moving the resource much slower than copying? My intuition is that, every call for std::move() requires the thread write to the string's header (a 24-byte block if I am right) for setting the pointers to nullptr. Because these headers are contiguous in memory, the writes will constantly attack the same cache line (64-byte block). Cache coherence mechanism kicks in and slows it down. In short, false sharing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing. I'd waste more time if had not missed std::move by accident. Tricky tricky..
@David Eisenstat 's suggestion is great. parlay::group_by_key() is very easy to use and is about 1.5x faster than the tbb::concurrent_unordered_map approach. Highly recommend it.
